# Find Max fiscal year data in excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

Hi I am trying to use MAX(range) on a column in a table of dates. Formatted as 2016-17, 2017-18, and so on. Any idea on how to do this with formulas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are they dates that are formatted to appear like that (like actual dates in the cell) or are these strings that are in that format?

Comment: No these are strings imputed in this format.

Comment: You could do `=DateValue(A1 & "-01")` in a new column and then take the max of that. I think the important part is getting those converted to a real date since you can't take the `max()` of a string.

Comment: What does "-01" do?

Comment: That concatenates the `-01` to the end of the date string like `2017-08` into `2017-08-01` (august 1st, 2018). The `DateValue()` then converts that full date string into an actual excel date (stored as a 5 digit number). It's pretty common when just wanting to deal with `YYYY-MM` that the actual date stored under the hood is the 1st of the month, so this fits that fairly common  whole thing.

Comment: Oh smart. Thank you!

Comment: Wait theirs an issue

Comment: Since these are fiscal years I get 2017-18-1 Which is invalid

Comment: That would definitely be a problem. Instead we can do math like `=(LEFT(A1, 4) * 100) + RIGHT(A1, 2)` to turn `2018-08` into `2018008` which will give you up to 999 fiscal periods per year if you need. then you can find the max of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the formula as below

[image]

Formula in cell D1 is an array formula which is to be entered using Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

it is

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$5,MATCH(MAX( --( (RIGHT($A$2:$A$5,2))) ),--(RIGHT($A$2:$A$5,2))))
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In order to achieve the above, Data Validation and 1 formula were used.

In the cell for the date you are looking for, use data validation.  Set the validation to use a list, and then select the date header row as the list.  In the example above it was set to B1:C1.  Then you just select the date you want to find the max of from the pull down that appear for the cell.  This is completely optional way of selecting the date that will save you typos or errors of looking for something that is not a match for a header in your data.

Finding the MAX.  use the following formula which is a combination of MAX, INDEX and MATCH.  You will match the date your are looking for in G1 to the appropriate column header in B1:C1.  Index will return the entire column that matches due to the 0.  MAX will then turn around and find the maximum number from that information.

```
=MAX(INDEX(B2:C4,0,MATCH(G1,B1:C1,0)))
```

Adjust and lock cell ranges to suit your data.

#### OPTIONAL DATE SELECTION

If you wind up having to select a column based on an actual date. you will need to know the the month and day of year that the fiscal year start or end on.  Based on being before or after that date, you will convert the date to a string that matches the format of your column headers and look up that way.

Example

Fiscal Year Starts April 1st

Date you want to look up is 2017/10/23 (H1)

```
=IF(H1<Date(Year(H1),4,1),(YEAR(H1)-1)&"-"&RIGHT(YEAR(H1),2),YEAR(H1)&"-"&RIGHT(YEAR(H1)+1,2))
```

The above could be used in lieu of the data validation method described earlier and would be placed in G1.